# .pyw program crashes upon execution, works as normal .py

Tags: python, flask, pythonw

I have a python program that I want to run without the console popping up. Naturally I went for a .pyw file to hide the console. However I noticed that after converting the file to a .pyw file. It would crash immediately upon executing.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling python and Flask. I ran the program within the Python IDLE and was finally able to get an error readout. I then looked it up and the answer ended up being "you have to run it in py". However the file runs completely fine on my desktop but not on my laptop or any other device that I have tried when set to a .pyw. This is the error traceback:

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
=========== RESTART: C:\Users\emidd\OneDrive\Desktop\FlaskApp.pyw ===========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emidd\OneDrive\Desktop\FlaskApp.pyw", line 16, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Users\emidd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 985, in run
    cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
  File "C:\Users\emidd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 670, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(message)
  File "C:\Users\emidd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 218, in echo
    file = _default_text_stdout()
  File "C:\Users\emidd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 675, in func
    rv = wrapper_func()
  File "C:\Users\emidd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 436, in get_text_stdout
    rv = _get_windows_console_stream(sys.stdout, encoding, errors)
  File "C:\Users\emidd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\click\_winconsole.py", line 295, in _get_windows_console_stream
    func = _stream_factories.get(f.fileno())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

I know that it can work because I have it running on my desktop, however I am not sure why it works on it but not my laptop. When it works, the readout on the IDLE is "running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/" if anyone could help me get this working with Pythonw that would be great. However it does technically work with normal python.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it on the commandline, IDLE has different IO objects which can mess with it.

Comment: it runs fine on IDLE on the desktop though. And the thing is I am trying to open the file with either a double click or from another program and it crashes both ways. I did test it though and it crashed as well